# Pass NULL parameter to TFDConnection.ExecSQLScalar

Tags: delphi, firedac

Is there a possibility to pass NULL value to some parameter of this FireDAC query?:

```
conn: TFDConnection;
fPar1, fPar2, fPar3: OleVariant;

cnt := conn.ExecSQLScalar(
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE par1=:p1 AND par2=:p2 AND par3=:p3',
    [fPar1, fPar2, fPar3]
);
```

Is it possible without intermediate `TFDQuery` using `TFDConnection` object only?

Comment: The problem is that `WHERE par1 = NULL` will give a different result than `WHERE par1 IS NULL`.

Comment: Isn't this where the ansi_nulls setting on the server comes into play. With ansi_nulls off then null = null is true, with ansi_nulls on then null = null is false.

Comment: @KeithMiller:  Actually, I think the reason the OP has asked is not to do with the result but rather that the overload of ExecSQLScalar he is using reacts by raising an exception with the msg quoted in my answer when it is passed a variant set to Null as a parameter.  But you are right about `ansi_nulls` needing to be set to `off` to get the expected results.

Comment: ansi_nulls soon will be deprecated. You need to use IS NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, despite the fact that the parameters TFDConnection uses
for ExecSQLScalar are not *directly* accessible from your calling code, but it may not produce the result you are expecting unless you modify your SQL - see below.

Presumably, you have had an error message like "[FireDAC] parameter type [fPar2 ] is unknown ..." if you set fPar2 to Null beforehand.

You can avoid that by using the override of ExecSQLScalar that allows you to specify
the field types of the parameters in an open array following the parameter
which lists the variants, as in e.g.

```
cnt := conn.ExecSQLScalar(
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE par1=:p1 AND par2=:p2 AND par3=:p3',
    [fPar1, fPar2, fPar3],
    [ftString, ftString, ftString] //  or whatever
);
```

See

```
function TFDCustomConnection.ExecSQLScalar(const ASQL: String;
  const AParams: array of Variant; const ATypes: array of TFieldType): Variant;
```

in FireDAC.Comp.Client.Pas

BUT, on my data here, this does NOT produce the correct count value (using Seattle and SS2014) presumably because of Uwe Raabe's good point about `par1 = Null` versus `par1 is Null`.  To get the correct answer, I had to modify the SQL as per Keith Miller's comment to include `set ansi_nulls off` before `SELECT ...`

Comment: I checked with MSSQL and the results are usually different. Especially `par1 = NULL` seems to always evaluate to false.

Comment: @Paul:  Did this help with your q?